# How update a table multiple times in Oracle SQL using java-using multithread or loops

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

Now I have to update this into my database, the problem is I don't know how to update it multiple times in the database.

```
public void generate() {
    KpiMsg804 upd = createKpiMsg804();
    try {
          st = conn.createStatement();
          System.out.println("Updating Values");
          //Updating Values into DB
          String query = "insert into msg_new_to_bde("
              + "tablename,action,keyinfo1,keyinfo2) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
          pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
          pstmt.setString(1,upd.getTableName());
          pstmt.setInt(2,upd.getAction()); // set value of staus of action
          pstmt.setString(3,upd.getKeyInfo1()); // set keyinfo value1
          pstmt.setString(4,upd.getKeyInfo2()); // set keyinfo value2
          int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
          System.out.println("Number of Rows Updated" +rows);
          // execute insert statement
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to execute the same `INSERT` statement with different values several times?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple updates? you are inserting a single record each time, so it just inserts one record each time.

Comment: Yes I need to do insert multiple times and change this status to another after doing a calculation, but first I have to insert multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the JDBC addBatch() and executeBatch() functionality: [JDBC insert multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012592/jdbc-insert-multiple-rows) . This will let you queue up your multiple rows, then insert them in one group.

The other interpretation of your question is: you need to turn the autocommit off, then use the JDBC begin() and commit() functionality to insert into several different tables, and they all go in at the same time.

```
pstmt.executeUpdate(Table1);
pstmt.executeUpdate(Table2);
conn.commit();
```

This will insert all the rows as one transaction, that is all at once.

Comment: This is not how you use batched statements. `executeUpdate()` is only called once per batch, not once for each insert. Additionally there is no `Connection.begin()` in JDBC

Comment: executeUpdate() needs to be execute once for each table in the group of inserts. I removed the (implicity) conn.begin().