# Java SQL says I have incorrect sytax but running the query in the shell works

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, syntax

I'm trying to insert into my database, but I get `SQLException: Problem in your syntax, line 2`.
So I printed to the console the query before running it and then pasted it to the SQL shell and it ran without problems. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help.

```
Utilizador u = new Aluno("A55555","password","cinco@email.com","Cinco",false,new HashMap<>());
new UserDAO().put(u.getUserNum(),u);
```

SQL query produced:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `Utilizador` (id, nome,pass, Email)
VALUES ('A55555', 'Cinco', 'password', 'cinco@email.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
  pass=VALUES(pass),
  nome=VALUES(nome),
  Email=VALUES(Email);
INSERT INTO `Aluno` (Utilizador_id, eEspecial)
VALUES ('A55555',0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Utilizador_id=VALUES(Utilizador_id),
                            eEspecial=VALUES(eEspecial);
```

Java:

```
String sql = "START TRANSACTION;\n" +
        "INSERT INTO `Utilizador` (id, nome,pass, Email) \n" +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)\n" +
        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),\n" +
        "                        pass=VALUES(pass),\n" +
        "                        nome=VALUES(nome),\n" +
        "                        Email=VALUES(Email);\n";
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(sql);
if (value instanceof Docente){
    s.append("INSERT INTO `Docente` (Utilizador_id)\n" +
             "VALUES (?)\n" +
             "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Utilizador_id=VALUES(Utilizador_id);");
}else if (value instanceof Aluno){
    s.append("INSERT INTO `Aluno` (Utilizador_id, eEspecial)\n" +
             "VALUES (?,?)\n" +
             "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Utilizador_id=VALUES(Utilizador_id), eEspecial=VALUES(eEspecial);");
}else if (value instanceof DiretorDeCurso){
    s.append("INSERT INTO `DiretorDeCurso` (Utilizador_id)\n" +
             "VALUES (?)" +
             "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Utilizador_id=VALUES(Utilizador_id);\n");
}else{
    return null;
}
System.out.println(s.toString());
PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(s.toString());
stm.setString(1, value.getUserNum());
stm.setString(2, value.getName());
stm.setString(3, value.getPassword());
stm.setString(4, value.getEmail());
stm.setString(5, value.getUserNum());
if(value instanceof Aluno) stm.setBoolean(6,((Aluno) value).eEspecial());
System.out.println(stm.toString());
stm.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. Note that you're executing several queries in a single statement. That might be accepted by MySQL, but it's generally not.

Comment: It's also odd to explicitly include `\n` in your SQL.

Comment: Transactions are usually started using the API instead of using an SQL-Statement... But I', not shure if this could be the reason of your particular problem

Comment: @JBNizet Multiple statements are only accepted if the MySQL connection is explicitly configured to do so (`allowMultiQueries=true`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC insert multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012592/jdbc-insert-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Statement` and `PreparedStatement` are for single statements, not multiple. You have to execute them one at a time.